# Threads and concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Does anyone know if there is a reliable way to set up a producer consumer type queue where the following holds:

1) Producer initially puts three objects on queue

2) Consumer consumes one item leaving two objects on queue

3) Control passes back to Producer and Producer puts one more item on - ( now 3 objects on queue again)

4) Consumer consumes one more item and the cycle continues hence

Please note I need to set up the solution manually without using any interfaces for an assignment I am working on. Any advice would be appreciated.

Is such fine tuning available with threads?

Comment: In a way, you're talking about a semaphore.

Comment: Java ..Apologies, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: If I understand this correctly: you want the `Consumer` to always wait until the queue is full?

Comment: see ArrayBlockingQueue. look at the source and you can mod it to fit your exact needs.

Comment: @millimoose Yeh, imagine the queue size is 3 and the consumer can only take something when queue is full. One way I was thinking of tackling the problem is: In the producer's run method, once the producer is finished has loaded the queue, a new consumer thread is spawned from the Producer's run method. The consumer thread joins - therefore it takes over activity until it has taken one item off the queue and then control returns to producer in a loop fashion. Is it bad practice to have the producer spawn new consumer worker threads??

Comment: @bosra Well, this is threading, there are no good practices. What you described sounds workable though. Just make sure there isn't a race condition between checking whether the queue is full and spawning a consumer. In a contrived situation where you know only the spawned consumers will be accessing the queue this should be safe. (The situation doesn't sound very practical, since to shut down a multithreaded system gracefully you generally want such queues to be emptied.)

Comment: @millimoose I hear ya. In this case I am trying to get a model working to demonstrate 'Starvation' of processes within the CPU where the higher priority processes continuously supersede the lower ranking background processes which results in the system not shutting down gracefully.

Answer (score 3):

What I would probably do is have a relatively mundane queue and also have a semaphore.  Initialize the semaphore to -2.  Have the producer increment the semaphore whenever it enqueues a request.  Have the consumer decrement the semaphore prior to dequeuing a request.  The consumer won't be able to do a decrement until the count gets to 1, and so there will always be 2 unserviced requests in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope this solution gives you some help:
```

Explanation goes as :

Two separate threads `(Producer thread and Consumer thread)` work in co-ordination with each other on a common queue(Here i have mentioned array). Producer puts three elements from a data array and consumer fetch one and remove that from same array.When data Array all elements are put in queue, consumer only fetches one-by-one. `put()` and `take()` are synchronized methods defined in a separate class `Drop`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ProducerConsumerExample {
    public static final Lock fileLock = new ReentrantLock();
    public static final Condition condition = fileLock.newCondition();
    public static String importantInfo[] = {
            "Mares eat oats",
            "Does eat oats",
            "Little lambs eat ivy",
            "A kid will eat ivy too",
            "abc",
            "def",
            "ghi",
            "jkl",
            "mno",
            "pqr"
    };
    public static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static boolean done = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Drop drop = new Drop();
        Thread tProducer = new Thread(new Producer(drop));
        Thread tConsumer = new Thread(new Consumer(drop));
        try{
        tProducer.start();
        tConsumer.start();
        }
        catch(Exception ie){}
    }
}

public class Consumer implements Runnable {
    private Drop drop;

    public Consumer(Drop drop) {
        this.drop = drop;
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            ProducerConsumerExample.fileLock.lock();
            for (String message = drop.take();
                    ! message.equals("DONE");
                    message = drop.take()) {
                System.out.format("MESSAGE RECEIVED: %s%n", message);
                ProducerConsumerExample.list.remove(0);
                if(ProducerConsumerExample.done)
                    continue;
                else{
                    ProducerConsumerExample.condition.signal();
                    System.out.println("Consumer is waiting");
                    ProducerConsumerExample.condition.await();
                }
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        finally{
            ProducerConsumerExample.fileLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Producer implements Runnable {
    private Drop drop;
    public Producer(Drop drop) {
        this.drop = drop;
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            ProducerConsumerExample.fileLock.lock();
            Random random = new Random();int check = 3;

            for (int i = 0;
                    i <ProducerConsumerExample.importantInfo.length;
                    i++) {
                if(i<check){
                System.out.println("Putting message");
                System.out.println(ProducerConsumerExample.importantInfo[i]);
                drop.put(ProducerConsumerExample.importantInfo[i]);
                }
                else{
                    check = check+3;
                    i--;
                    ProducerConsumerExample.condition.signal();
                    System.out.println("Producer is waiting");
                    ProducerConsumerExample.condition.await();
                }
            }
            drop.put("DONE");
            ProducerConsumerExample.done =true;
            ProducerConsumerExample.condition.signal();
            System.out.println("Producer is waiting");
            ProducerConsumerExample.condition.await();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            ProducerConsumerExample.fileLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Drop {
    // Message sent from producer
    // to consumer.
    private String message;
    public synchronized String take() {
        System.out.println(ProducerConsumerExample.list.size());
        return ProducerConsumerExample.list.get(0);
    }

    public synchronized void put(String message) {
        // Store message.
        ProducerConsumerExample.list.add(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add description regarding how this code work which help other to understand better.

Comment: Can you provide some example for achieving the same using java Executors and Blocking Queue

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 has a [LinkedTransferQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html) which sounds like what you are looking for, or check out the parent type [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), I'm sure one of them will fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ArrayList and set the capacity to 3; then, anytime the Producer executes, the array size is checked; if the size is lower than 3, simply insert values to the ArrayList till the size is 3; if the size is 3; just call the *notifyAll()* method to finish its turn. 
      Similarly for the Consumer, if the size is 3, consume one of the values, and remove it from the ArrayList; if the size is less than 3, simply call the *notifyAll()* method to finish its turn. 
 
     This is basically how it works in a nutshell; the implementation will depend on what you plan to achieve with it. 
 
     Hope this helps.

Comment: It is probably worth adding that ArrayLists are not thread safe and all these operations would need some form of synchronization.

Comment: I understand that; my assumption is that, he already has the specifics of threading covered. ArrayBlockingQueue is an example of a class he could use, if he doesn't want to use the **synchronized** keyword.